# Different Header Files Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, header

I made ​​a wordpress theme, I have some header files.
I would like to appear on the Appearance> Menus such as:

```
- Header
-- Header 1
-- Header 2
-- Header 3
```

with Header 1, 2 and 3 call header1.php, header2.php, header3.php file.
how can I do that?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header is a menu you add and header 1 / 2 / 3 are submenus then you have to follow these articles:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_page
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page